# ASP.NET Core : how can I replace a character at int values in foreach or for loop?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have a loop whose values ​​are int. The values ​​are displayed in this way: `14 16 18`.

I want to place a dash `-` between the numbers of the characters: `14-16-18`

I searched a lot and did not find a suitable solution :(

Loop:

```
foreach (int size in SizeList)
{
    <span class="size">@size </span>
}
```

Comment: @easleyfixed The numbers are not fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also be able to handle the task with the [Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join) method of the string class

```
<span>class="size">@(string.Join("-", sizeList.Select(i => i.ToString())))</span>
```

or, possibly using a more defensive style of coding if you are in danger of null reference exceptions here:

```
@if(sizeList is not null)
{
    <span>class="size">@(string.Join("-", sizeList.Select(i => i.ToString())))</span>
}
```

Actually, the explicit conversion to string is not necessary as in the answer given by @Dave Bry so you can get by with less code too:

```
<span>class="size">@string.Join("-", sizeList)</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

EDITED for correctness:

My previous solution was incorrect and didn't exactly provide what you were looking for, it's been a while since I wrote Razor syntax.

Playing around with it a little more, there's one line of code that can provide what you're looking for without having to loop over the array/list:

```html
<span class="sizes">@string.Join("-", SizeList)</span>
```

That will give you the output of `14-16-18` or whatever `SizeList` contains.

Comment: How to add "-" to numbers?

Comment: @RoyalDesigner I rewrote my answer, my previous solution didn't exactly work and wouldn't have helped. My new answer should provide you with what you're looking for.